# how to select a column in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Query:

```
select c.id, sum(case when r.paid_out>='1' then 0 else 1 end) as all_paids
from people p1, houses h, policies p2, receipts r
where p1.id = h.id
and h.code = p2.code
and p2.code_policy = r.code_policy
group by p1.id
having all_paids= 0;
```

Postesql return me the following error:

ERROR : There is no column 'all_paids'

I have tried several things but nothing, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `join` syntax.

Second, you can use the expression for the `having` clause or a subquery:

```
select p1.id
from people p1 join
     houses h
     on p1.id = h.id join
     policies p2
     on h.code = p2.code join
     receipts r
     on p2.code_policy = r.code_policy
group by p1.id
having sum(case when r.paid_out >= '1' then 0 else 1 end) = 0;
```

Note:  there is no `c.id` defined, so I assume the `select` should be `p1.id` based on the `group by`.

I should say that this logic would often be expressed using `not exists`:

```
select p1.*
from people p1
where not exists (select 1
                  from houses h
                       policies p2
                       on h.code = p2.code join
                       receipts r
                       on p2.code_policy = r.code_policy
                  where p1.id = h.id and
                        r.paid_out >= '1'
                 );
```

This eliminates the aggregation.